# =0A in the subject of an email sent with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this in my user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: ["no-reply@#{CONFIG[:domain]}"]

  def password_reset(user, portal_name)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: t('emails.password_reset.subject')
  end
end
```

I have this in my yml translation file:

```
emails:
  password_reset:
    subject: You've requested to reset your password
```

There are no characters at the end of the translation string, however when the email is sent the subject appears like this in the email: "You've requested to reset your password=0A"

I've tried searching for an answer and I found Rails used to have an ActionMailer::Quoting.quoted_printable method, but it seems this no longer exists in rails 4.

Where is the "=0A" coming from? Any built-in solution to this in rails?

Comment: What happens if you add quotes to your translation, as in: 'You've requested to reset your password'

Comment: Not much:

With quotes p I18n.t('emails.password_reset.subject')
"You've requested to reset your password"

without quotes: p I18n.t('emails.password_reset.subject')
"You've requested to reset your password"

So I really don't understand where the =0A is coming from :/

Comment: That's some line ending getting botched somewhere in the mix. What happens if you do this: `t('emails.password_reset.subject').html_safe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding a chomp at the end:

```
mail to: user.email, subject: t('emails.password_reset.subject').chomp
```

It seems a newline was being introduced somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when using the 'X-SMTPAPI' header(SendCloud Mail Service).This is because [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb#L191) will handle the headers:

```
def encode_crlf(value)
  value.gsub!(CR, CR_ENCODED)
  value.gsub!(LF, LF_ENCODED)
  value
end
```

When I tried using Mail gem only, it worked. I think this is because the charset is different with Rails' default setting. I solved the issue like this:

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = Base64.encode64(JSON.dump({"to" => emails, "sub" => {"%name%" => names}})).gsub!(/\n/,'')
```